# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: column contents.app_id does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pg

Having issues after upgrading rails from 3.0.20 => 3.1.12. When I run the unit test, some tests pass, but I get 8 errors and 18 failures. The error is `column doesn't exist`.

==================================================================================
here's one of my error:

```
Error: test_the_results_of_searching_content_model_by_keyword_is_two(SearchRecordsTest)
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column contents.app_id does not exist
  LINE 1: ...%') OR "contents"."copyrighter" LIKE '%Food%') OR "contents"...
                                                               ^
  : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contents"  WHERE (((((((("contents"."content_id_token" LIKE '%Food%' OR "contents"."name" LIKE '%Food%') OR "contents"."description" LIKE '%Food%') OR "contents"."copyrighter" LIKE '%Food%') OR "contents"."app_id" IN (SELECT "apps"."id" FROM "apps"  WHERE "apps"."app_id_token" LIKE '%Food%')) OR "contents"."app_id" IN (SELECT "apps"."id" FROM "apps"  WHERE "apps"."name" LIKE '%Food%')) OR "contents"."author_id" IN (SELECT "authors"."id" FROM "authors"  WHERE "authors"."name" LIKE '%FoodFood')) OR "contents"."author_id" IN (SELECT "authors"."id" FROM "authors"  WHERE "authors"."name_kana" LIKE '%Food%')))
test/unit/search_records_test.rb:26:in `check_results'
test/unit/search_records_test.rb:53:in `block in search_and_check_results_common_process'
test/unit/search_records_test.rb:47:in `each'
test/unit/search_records_test.rb:47:in `search_and_check_results_common_process'
test/unit/search_records_test.rb:79:in `block in <class:SearchRecordsTest>'
```

and here's the test code.

```
test 'the results of searching content model  by keyword is two' do
    expected_records  = [:content12, :content13]
    search_text       = 'Food'
    with_column       = { content: { type: 0 } }

    search_and_check_results_common_process(Content, search_text, with_column, expected_records)
  end
```

Comment: try running `rake db:test:prepare` first before running the test suite.  also make sure that you run your migrations first.

Comment: i already run migration for db test, and i have two db one for development and one for test. in rails 3.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3 it work got no error with missing column.. @jvnill

Comment: sorry if yo're sure that the column exists in your test db, then I have no other idea.

Comment: at the very beginning the column doesn't exist, but when i run unit test in ruby 1.9.3, it succeded. but know it can't. @jvnill